# Can I guess the Rds(on) at 3.3 V from this MOSFET datasheet?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

I ordered some MOSFET switch modules. Because they were advertised as "for Arduino" and "Voltage: 3.3V, 5V", I assumed they had chosen a decent MOSFET for the job (like the IRLU7843 or at least the IRLZ34N). There is no additional circuitry on the modules.

Now I see that they use the IRF520, which struck me as odd, as I remember them to be a bad fit for a microcontroller project.

[Here's a datasheet.](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91017/91017.pdf) Is there a way to guess the R<sub>DS(on)</sub> at V<sub>GS</sub> = 3.3 V or 4.5 V from it?

Comment: (1) You're right when you say that IRF520 doesn't make a great logic level MOSFET.  (2) When you say "\$R_{ds(on)}\$ at 4.5 V", do you mean \$V_{DS} = V_{GS} = \$ 4.5V ?

Comment: Guessing is not required as the information is in the graphs. It also tells you, you need at least 4V GS so forget about 3V3.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yes, at least \$V_{GS}\$. \$V_{DS}\$ usually doesn't matter that much, does it?

Comment: @Oldfart Oh, Fig. 3, I completely missed that. You want to add an answer?

Comment: You want to operate the MOSFET in the ohmic region, when you want to operate the MOSFET as a switch.  The ohmic region is where the characteristic line (fig.3) is sloped.  Notice that \$V_{DS}\$ is the horizontal axis on fig.3 .  For example, when the \$V_{GS} = \$ 4.5V, the ohmic region is between \$V_{DS} =\$ 0V and \$V_{DS} =\$ 1V.  So, \$V_{DS}\$ matters too.

Comment: _I ordered some MOSFET switch modules. Because they were advertised as "for Arduino"_ - It seems like every other thingy on Ebay/DX is advertised as "for Arduino", even if it's something like a bare LED (no series resistor). The "for Arduino" qualification is bordering on useless on those sites, at least.

Comment: Well, they have just arrived and while they do switch with 3.32 V, they have a resistance of about 440 Ohms (1.92 V voltage drop at 4.37 mA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure 3 show that I<sub>D</sub> starts at 0 at V<sub>GS</sub> of 4Volts. The specifications lists the threshold V<sub>GS(th)</sub> as 2.0...4.0V so I assume the graph is for the 4V worst case. No operation at 3V3!

Assuming you want to use it as a switch, figure 1 shows I<sub>D</sub> is 1 Amp at V<sub>GS</sub> and V<sub>DS</sub> around 4.5V so that would mean a R<sub>D(on)</sub> of about 4.5 Ohms.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at graph 1 you get the drain current per drain-source voltage for each gate-source voltage.

[image: IRF520 outout graph]

The fact that Vgs 4.5V already limits the Id to 1A, means the Rdson is high.
You will need a gate driver.